# Updating custom fields with data from the database

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm having a real problem with updating advanced custom fields (within a custom post type) with data from the database.

I have a table in the database called 'wp_company_profiles' with fields 'address_1' and 'address_2', and have two advanced custom fields set up with the same values. I am trying to put together a hook that will pull data from the database to occupy the custom fields with when a particular post is displayed.

Below is the code I am using, but I'm sure there is something I'm missing but can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
function get_fields_company_profile($post_ID)  {
    global $wpdb;

    if ($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )) $post_ID = $parent_id;

    $row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_company_profiles WHERE pid => '$post_ID' LIMIT 1" );

    $address1 = $row->address_1;
    $address2 = $row->address_2;

    update_post_meta($post_ID, 'address_1', $address1);
    update_post_meta($post_ID, 'address_2', $address2);

}
add_action('init', 'get_fields_company_profile');
```

Comment: Are you sure the query returns a result? Print the `$row` to see the result. I can see the query being wrong. Check this `WHERE pid => '$post_ID'`. Should not this be `WHERE pid = '$post_ID'`? This is assuming you have only one such record for a post and retrieving value for that post only. Also not sure why you are using `update_post_meta` when you are speaking about displaying the data.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the '>' after the equals. Have fixed that but still not working. I'm using update_post_meta as there are custom fields set with values 'address_1' and 'address_2'. I want to update these fields with what is currently in the database. Posts for this particular post type are being entered through a web form, which only retrieves the title and content, whereas the rest of the data (i.e. address 1, address 2) gets put into the database with no way for the client to update the data themselves.

Comment: You have still not mentioned whether the above query returned any result or not. Print the result in the code, then confirm here. Another question: when there is only one record for a post, why you are using LIMIT 1? Also where this data will be shown: on admin custom post edit screen or on some other place like frontend?

Comment: Where is this code intended to run? As is, it runs on every page load, front and back. I am _sure_ that that is wrong and I am sure for some page loads it generating at the least a string of `Notice`s that you would see if you [debugging turned on](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: You've also got a typo in there: your function parameter is called `$post_ID`, but two lines down you use `$post_id`. Variable names in PHP are case-sensitive.

Comment: Ok so just seen that theres a problem with `WHERE pid = '$post_ID'`. Its not printing any results, whereas if I assign a variable to grab the post id `$pid = $_GET['post'];` and the add `WHERE pid => '$pid'`, print_r returns the results fine. However, this hasn't fixed the overall issue. 

I need the code to run in the admin area only for posts. I have set custom text fields where I need the data to appear. Also, I have taken out LIMIT 1, as you are right, not needed.

Comment: I have used `init` as it loads on every page. Maybe it isn't what I should use but I don't think that is the problem.

Have you any ideas from here?